# IBM Watson - Rank items based users reveled preferences

Tags: ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank, personality-insights

In an ecommerce website, users can bookmark products and bookmark other users.

I'd like to display a custom feed of products for logged-in users.

Questions:

1) How to get products user would like most, based on the similarity of products they bookmarked.

2) What services should best fit this use case?

I though in 'retrieve-and-rank' as starting point, but maybe 'Personality Insights' also should be used in conjunction with retrieve-and-rank.

Can you provide a simple code or query as example?

Answer (score 0):

There is one example available in Watson Starter kit "Answer Retrieval app" to customize R&R.Below is the link
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/answer-retrieval